# Apache centos IP based access

Tags: apache, centos, vhosts

I have a Centos 6 web server running around 50 sites based on virtual hosts setup.

Recently i have been asked to restrict access to the web sites only from within my organisation.

Having "Order deny,allow" at each virtual host works fine i.e anyone from outside the organisation are not able to visit the website/s but users only from with the organisation are able to get to the sites.

My question is, is there a way i can do this setup at httpd.conf so that it applies to all the sites getting served from this box rather than repeating the "Order deny,allow" settings on every virtual host. If it can be done at global server level, can someone please let me know how.

Restricting at firewall level or proxy is not an option so had to be done at web server level.

Appreciate the help

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put a `<Directory>` block at root level of your config, and apply it to the lowest common root of your web directories. For example, if they are in /home:

```
<Directory "/home">
    Order deny,allow
    ...
</Directory>
```

But remember that this will then apply to anything in /home, which could be a security concern. You could improve on that by using [DirectoryMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch) and specifying a pattern that would only affect website folders specifically, such as:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/[^/]+/public_html">
    Order deny,allow
    ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

If your web folders were of the format `/home/user/public_html`. Let me know your directory structure and I can update the answer.